# Migration data from Access database to Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-access

**First Approach:**
I have Microsoft access database which has multiple relationships within a table. I have tried to import data into SharePoint list but an issue is that every time it is creating a new list for relation table. hence, I have multiple lists with same data and I can not maintain lookup.

**Second Approach:**
I have created a console application to insert data using CSOM into SharePoint online, but it is taking so much time.

As we are inserting records using CSOM, this approach insertion is done by one by one record and each record is taking at-least one second to update in a list. hence I am looking for an option like a bulk insertion.

Do we have any other approach to migrating data from access database to SharePoint online?

Comment: What is the problem with performance in the second approach? Do you know where the bottleneck is?

Comment: As we are inserting records using CSOM, this approach insertion is done by one by one record and each record is taking at-least one second to update in list. hence i am looking for option like bulk insertion.

Comment: Perhaps this gives an idea: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a583441b-4885-40c5-ac2a-ad298f818afc/bulk-insert-in-client-object-model?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Comment: sure, i will look into it, just one doubt about this bulk insert is 'how it will be handle lookup column'?

Comment: I did not tested it

Comment: What about an Access App?

Comment: @Yugo, Can you please share entire approach ?

Comment: As I haven't played extensively with Access App in SPO, I found this information -an old thread- for you to check out, and see if it might help https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/01/27/access-database-office365/